# Capistrano 3 role based linked files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Is it possible to configure Capistrano 3 to link different files based on a role using built-in `linked_files`?

I have servers with a role `worker`, which don't need to have web-stuff related files linked (i.e. `sitemap.xml` file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, variables in Capistrano (e.g. `:linked_files`) are global and cannot have different values per host/role.

You could possibly make it work by redefining the `deploy:symlink:linked_files` and `deploy:check:linked_files` tasks with your own custom implementation. That implementation could, for example, perform different linking for different roles.

```
Rake::Task["deploy:symlink:linked_files"].clear_actions

task "deploy:symlink:linked_files" do
  on release_roles(:web) do
    execute :ln, "-s", ...
    execute :ln, "-s", ...
    # etc.
  end
  on release_roles(:app) do
    execute :ln, "-s", ...
    execute :ln, "-s", ...
    # etc.
  end
end
```

However, I would recommend against this for two reasons:

1. It is a lot of code to write
2. You lose Capistrano "magic" where Capistrano plugins inject things into `:linked_files`

Comment: Thanks, great summary. I ended up adding an extra task which runs after `deploy:symlink:linked_files` and is invoked only on `web` role.

Answer (score 0):

`no_release: true` will skip linking files. This was enough in my case for `web` role as we only upload maintenance page there.